# Let G be a k-edge-connected graph with n ≥ 3. For any e ∈ E(G), show that G/e is k-edge- connected.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Could someone help me with this question.
My thought is that proof by contradiction. But I don't know which direction should I start with...

Comment: What's your definition of $G/e$? For the most common version, contracting a spoke of a [wheel graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph) seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: G/e is edge contraction here

Comment: I figured *that* much. I was hoping to find out which definition of edge contraction you were using, but if you don't want to provide any details beyond the bare minimum then I'm sure you'll get somewhere on your own eventually.

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought there was only one definition of edge contraction. The defintion i am using is to delete the edge and merge the endpoints of e. Meanwhile, I think I have an approach how to prove it. Basically, I will say it has at least k-edge disjoint paths from any two distinct vertices in G and discuss for different cases. But not sure if it's the right track.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must be careful with the definitions here. Consider any $k$-edge-connected graph which has a vertex $u$ of degree $k$ with two neighbors $v,w$ that are also adjacent to each other. Then contracting edge $vw$ will reduce the degree of $u$ to $k-1$, disproving the claim...

...unless we make sure to define the contraction $G/vw$ as a multigraph, so that a vertex $u$ adjacent to both $v$ and $w$ will have two parallel edges to the contracted vertex $G/vw$. This preserves the degree.

---

With the multigraph definition, while we could do tricky things, just reasoning from the definition works.

There is a bijection between the edges in $G$ other than $e$ and the edges in $G/e$: edges to an endpoint of $e$ become edges to the contracted vertex.

All paths in $G$ remain paths in $G/e$ under this bijection: if a path simply passes through an endpoint of $e$, it now passes through the contracted vertex, and if it uses $e$, it becomes shorter.

A set of edges $S$ is a cut if we can find two vertices $x,y$ such that all $x-y$ paths contain an edge of $S$. By the observation above, if $S$ is an edge cut in $G/e$, the image of $S$ under the bijection is an edge cut in $G$. Assuming $G$ is $k$-edge-connected, the cut in $G$ has at least $k$ edges, and therefore the cut in $G/e$ must have had at least $k$ edges.